# ReactJS getting an Enter Key to do the same thing as the button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this website made in react (https://animeimages.netlify.com/).  You basically put a series name in the search bar, click the button and it returns images. But when you click enter, the page just restarts.  Is it possible to press enter and have it do the same thing as clicking the search button.  The form and the button are different components.

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, InputGroup, Form, } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Conditional from './conditional'
import Button2 from './button.js'


class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            isLoading2: true,
            query: '',
            fimg: [],
        }
        this.isloaded = this.isLoaded.bind(this)

    }
    isLoaded  = () => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: !this.state.isLoading,
            isLoading2: false
        })

    }

    fimgSet = fimgData => {
        this.setState({
            fimg: fimgData
        });
    }


    render(){
        return(
        <div className="App">
            <div className="App-title"> <span className="bg-title"> Anime Image Gallery </span></div>
            <div className="app-mini-title"> <span className="bg-title">Enter the name of an Anime series</span></div>
            <Form className="OutterformSize">
            <FormGroup>
                {/* <Form.Label> <span className=".bg-title">Enter the name of an Anime series </span></Form.Label> */}

                <InputGroup className="formSize">
                    <FormControl
                        size="lg"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Try Searching Pokémon, DRAGON+BALL or Wallpaper"
                        value = {this.state.query}
                        onChange= {event => {this.setState({query: event.target.value})}}


                        />
                </InputGroup>
            </FormGroup>
            <Button2  query={this.state.query} isLoading={this.state.isLoading} isLoaded={this.isLoaded} callbackFromParent={this.fimgSet}/>
            </Form>
            <div>
                <Conditional images={this.state.fimg} isLoading2={this.state.isLoading2}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

button.js

```
import React from "react";
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner';
import { ButtonToolbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import  Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'


class Button2 extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.OnSearch = this.OnSearch.bind(this)
    }

    OnSearch(){
        this.props.isLoaded();
        // console.log("Seatch Clicked");
        // console.log(this.props.query)
        const $ = require('cheerio');
        const BASE_URL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.zerochan.net/'
        const DYM_URL = `${BASE_URL}${this.props.query}?s=fav` //'Re%3AZero+Kara+Hajimeru+Isekai+Seikatsu' 
        // console.log(DYM_URL)
        // console.log(DYM_URL)
        //const URL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.zerochan.net/Re%3AZero+Kara+Hajimeru+Isekai+Seikatsu?screen=1&s=fav'
        // const request= require("request-promise") 
    // const $ = require('cheerio')
        // const url ="https://www.zerochan.net/n?s=fav"
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Accept' : "text/plain",
            'Content-Type': "text/plain",
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Mobile Safari/537.36'
        });
        fetch(DYM_URL, {
            method: "GET",
            mode: "cors",
            cache: "no-cache",
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            header: headers,
            //lss
        })
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(body => {
                // console.log(body)
                const imgUrls = [];
                const imgLen = $('p > a', body).length;
                for (let i = 0; i < imgLen; i++){
                    imgUrls[i]=($('p > a', body)[i].attribs.href);
                }
                const regex = /https:\/\/static.zerochan.net.+.(jpg|png)/
                const match = imgUrls.filter(value =>  regex.test(value));
                // console.log("match: ", match);

                this.props.callbackFromParent(match);
                this.props.isLoaded();

                // this.setState({
                //     fimg: match
                // })

            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);

            });
        }

        render(){
            if (this.props.isLoading === false){
                return(
                <div>
                    <ButtonToolbar className="text-center d-block">
                    <Button variant="primary">
                        <Spinner
                        as="span"
                        animation="border"
                        size="sm"
                        role="status"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                        />
                        Loading
                    </Button>
                    </ButtonToolbar>
                </div>
                /* <div>
                    {}
                </div> */

            )} else {
            return(
                <div>
                    <ButtonToolbar className="text-center d-block">
                        <Button variant="primary" type="button"  onClick={() => this.OnSearch()}>Search</Button>
                    </ButtonToolbar>
                </div>

                // <div>
                // <button type="button"  onClick={() => this.OnSearch()}>search</button>
                // </div>
                )}

        }
}


export default Button2;
```

The github repo: **https://github.com/Kohdz/ImageScraper**

Answer (score 0):

You should move the event handler to the `<form>` `onSubmit` and remove the `onClick` event from the `<button>`, which will result in the form submission being triggered when you either hit enter on the keyboard or click on the button.